# Set breakpoint from .perldb init file

Tags: perl, perldb

I am experimenting with the [`.perldb`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html#Debugger-Customization) rc file and trying to set a breakpoint. Here is a small sample script that I use for testing (**p.pl**):

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

say "Line 5";
say "Line 6";
say "Line 7";
```

Then, I created the following `.perldb` file in the current directory:

```
parse_options("NonStop=1");
sub afterinit { push @DB::typeahead, "b 7" }
```

(Note that this file should not have write permission by other than yourself (i.e. : `chmod 644 .perldb`) or else the debugger will not load it). Then I run the script under the debugger:

```
$ perl -d p.pl
Line 5
Line 6
Line 7
```

As seen the breakpoint at line 7 is not respected. What can be the problem here?

Comment: Doesn't "NonStop=1" turn off interactive use, thus disables breakpoints?

Comment: @BarneySchmale Yes that seems to be the case! But if I turn off `NonStop`, it will stop at line 5 first (the beginning of the program), then if I press `c` (for continue) it will run until it hits the breakpoint at line 7. How can I avoid that it first stops at line 5?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing your ".perldb-File" to

```
#parse_options("NonStop=1");
sub afterinit { push @DB::typeahead, ("b 7", "c") }
```

should do the job.

```
$ perl -d t.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.51
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(t.pl:5): say "Line 5";
auto(-2)  DB<1> b 7
auto(-1)  DB<2> c
Line 5
Line 6
main::(t.pl:7): say "Line 7";

DB<2> l
7==>b   say "Line 7";
```