# How to set breakpoint in a required module from a .perldb init file?

Tags: perl, perldb

A follow-up question to [Set breakpoint from .perldb init file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61571488/2173773). I am trying to set a breakpoint in a module that is loaded at run time. For testing purposes I have created the following files:

**`/home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/p.pl`**:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib "./lib";

say "Line 6";
say "Line 7";
require My::Module;
say "Line 9";
```

**`/home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/lib/My/Module.pm`**

```
package My::Module;
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;

say "MM Line 6";
say "MM Line 7";
say "MM Line 8";

1;
```

**`/home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/.perldb`**

```
sub afterinit {
    push @DB::typeahead,
      "b p.pl:8",
      "c",
      "b /home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/lib/My/Module.pm:7",
      "c"
      ;
}
```

When I run the script with the debugger, I get:

```
$ perl -d p.pl

Loading DB routines from perl5db.pl version 1.55
Editor support available.

Enter h or 'h h' for help, or 'man perldebug' for more help.

main::(p.pl:6): say "Line 6";
auto(-4)  DB<1> b p.pl:8
auto(-3)  DB<2> c
Line 6
Line 7
main::(p.pl:8): require My::Module;
auto(-2)  DB<2> b /home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/lib/My/Module.pm:7
auto(-1)  DB<3> c
MM Line 6
MM Line 7
MM Line 8
Line 9
Debugged program terminated.  Use q to quit or R to restart,
use o inhibit_exit to avoid stopping after program termination,
h q, h R or h o to get additional info.
```

So the the breakpoint at line 7 of `Module.pm` is ignored. How can I make the debugger stop at the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one cannot set a breakpoint in the required module before it has been compiled, but it is possible to work around the issue by using the [`b load filename`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldebug.html) command first, and then setting the breakpoint since then the required module will already have been compiled:

```
sub afterinit {
    push @DB::typeahead,
      "b p.pl:8",
      "c",
      "b load lib/My/Module.pm",
      "c",
      "b lib/My/Module.pm:7",
      "c"
      ;
}
```

This works for me.

### Note:

If I had used

```
use FindBin qw/$Bin/;
use lib "$Bin/lib";
```

instead of

```
use lib './lib';
```

in the script `p.pl`, I would have to use absolute paths with the `b` commmand instead of relative paths:

```
sub afterinit {
    push @DB::typeahead,
      "b p.pl:8",
      "c",
      "b load /home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/lib/My/Module.pm",
      "c",
      "b /home/hakon/test/perl/perldb/lib/My/Module.pm:7",
      "c"
      ;
}
```